# How to solve system of linear equations with negative scalars over finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I need to solve the homogeneous system of linear equations over $Z_7$ via matrix:

\begin{cases}
    \frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{2}y+4z -t = 0 \\
    4x - z +3t = 0
  \end{cases}

So this is the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{2} & 4 & -1 \\
    4 & 0 & -1 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
I can't arrive to the correct solution which I checked in Wolfram Alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((2%2F3)x+-+0.5y%2B4z+-t)+mod+7%3D0,+(4x+-+z+%2B3t)+mod+7%3D0. Can you please point the incorrect transitions I'm making? (I have to use Gaussian elimination for this)

First of all, my assumption is that if we have negative numbers I need to translate them immediately into  $Z_7$ so the matrix becomes after switching first and second row:

1)
\begin{bmatrix}
     4 & 0 & 6 & 3 \\
    \frac{2}{3} & 6.5 & 4 & 6
  \end{bmatrix} 
2) $R_1 \to 4^{-1}R_1$
 \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 5 & 3 \\
    \frac{2}{3} & 6.5 & 4 & 6
  \end{bmatrix} 
3) $R_2 \to R_2 - \frac{2}{3}R_1$
 \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 5 & 3 \\
    0 & 6.5 & \frac{2}{3} & 4
  \end{bmatrix} 
4) $R_2 \to \frac{10}{65}R_2$ because $6.5^{-1} = \frac{10}{65}$ over $Z_7$
 \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 5 & 3 \\
    0 & 1 & \frac{4}{39} & \frac{8}{13}
  \end{bmatrix}

Now the matrix looks canonical but I can clearly see that it's not the solution from Worlfram.

Comment: The "set of reduced representatives" is too narrow a view for doing arithmetic conveniently. More productive is the one where $-1$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$; it's just the *same* element as $6$. Use whichever representation of the element that is most convenient at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just how you got rid of negative numbers, you should get rid of all fractions too. After all, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field, isn't it? For example, since $3\cdot5=15=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, the reciprocal of $3$ is $\frac{1}{3}=3^{-1}=5$, and so you can simplify $\frac{2}{3}=2\cdot3^{-1}=2\cdot5=10=3$. (Or you can guess directly that $3\cdot3=9=2$, so $2/3=3$.) Then your original matrix, after switching rows as you did, becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 6 & 3 \\ 3 & 3 & 4 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then you can continue with the Gauss-Jordan method from there. Just don't use any fractions! Every time you need a reciprocal for an elimination step, find that reciprocal in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

**UPDATE.** And I found an arithmetical error in your work. The matrix you obtained in step 2) should have $6$, not $3$, as the last entry of the first row.

Comment: I thought that fraction $\mod 7$ will just remain a fraction, thanks for pointing out that I should translate them into $Z_7 $ as well. After doing so I get the end matrix as $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 5 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$. is this correct?

Comment: @Yos: Yes, I got the same thing.

Comment: @ zipirovich: but how does this add up to Wolfram Alpha answer? We get $x = -5z-6t$ and $y = -z-3t$ thus the answer is $(-5z-6t, -z-3t, z, t)$ while Wolfram says $0, (4x-z+3t)$.

Comment: @Yos: WolframAlpha says that in the line where it reproduces the input, not where it gives solutions. Solutions are listed below, and not even all of them. If you read the solutions it gives, modulo $7$ it gives individual solutions, not a parametric family from Gauss-Jordan method. If you keep hitting "More solutions", I guess eventually it will generate all $49$ of them. (I haven't tried that, though.)

Comment: @ zipirovich: so there's really no way to check the solution of matrix form over a finite field in Wolfram? Do you know other software that does that? (Matlab, R)

Comment: @Yos: To be honest, I don't know an answer to that...

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 equations and 4 unknowns there will be a 2 dimensional solution

$z = z\\
t = t\\
4x = z-3t\\ 
x = \frac 14 z - \frac 34 t\\
\frac 12 y = \frac 23 x + 4z-t\\
y = 2(\frac 23)(\frac 14 z - \frac 34t) + 8z - 2t\\
y = \frac 13 z - t + 8z - 2t\\
y = \frac {25}{3} z - 3t$

or:

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac 14\\\frac {25}3\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}r + \begin{bmatrix}-\frac 34\\-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}s$

Now lets get that mod 7

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ 100\\12\\0\end{bmatrix}r + \begin{bmatrix}-3\\-12\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}s$

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ 2\\5\\0\end{bmatrix}r + \begin{bmatrix}4\\2\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}s$